How to fix long deep crack in plaster wall that exposes brick/conrete block behind
Back Story: My apartment is on top floor of a building that was built in 1950's, and I discovered several diagonal and some horizontal cracks after I removed the wallpapaer from the old owner.
I was prepping one of the cracks on my wall for filling with chisel, and I discovered that the crack was very deep. I kept going until I found concrete block (or brick, it is hard to tell for me) behind. Now I think the wall filler I bought might not be enough to fix it problem. Can anyone please give me advice on how to fix this?
There are several more cracks on the wall that I need to fix. So, guidance would be much appreciated.
Thank you.


It might be something to have an expert(local building inspector, structural engineer) look at.  The inside stuff seems to be cracked also.  On top floor I would like to know if just common settlement cracks or something more structural.

How deep is "very deep"? Plaster isn't structural, so usually all we are concerned with is patching the surface plus enough to support that service.

Thank you both for commenting. I talked to my building association, they said it is not their problem, so, I fixed the cracks my self. They were almost 10cm deep, and fortunately there was a powder wall filler that I could mix with water to fix this.
